# PHP running on virtual host doesn't create directory for images

Tags: php, file-upload, directory, virtualhost

This is my httpd-vhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/php-crash-course-2020/14_product_crud/03_good/public"
    ServerName products.test
    <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/php-crash-course-2020/14_product_crud/03_good/public">
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    RewriteEngine On
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

I have given all privileges to this folder with

```
sudo chown -R $USER /opt/lampp/htdocs/
```

Everything works fine if there is already an images folder inside the public folder but when I want to create a new product (image, title, description, price) it creates a product in the database with the correct image path but it does not create an images folder.

This is code for creating an images folder inside the public folder

```
if (!is_dir(__DIR__ . '/../public/images')) {
    mkdir(__DIR__ . '/../public/images');
}
```

This is code for moving an image file inside the images folder

```
if ($this->imageFile && $this->imageFile['tmp_name']) {

    if ($this->imagePath) {

        unlink(__DIR__ . '/../public/' . $this->imagePath);
    }
    $this->imagePath = 'images/' . UtilHelper::randomString(8) . '/' . $this->imageFile['name'];

    mkdir(dirname(__DIR__ . '/../public/' . $this->imagePath));
    move_uploaded_file($this->imageFile['tmp_name'], __DIR__ . '/../public/' . $this->imagePath);
}
```

If I already have the images folder and there is the image for a certain product, the image can be loaded on the website and I can delete that product but when I delete it, the image inside the images folder is not deleted but it should be.

The application works when I run it on a PHP server as

```
php -S localhost:8080
```

Comment: You need to make sure that the user the web server runs as (usually www-data on Apache/linux) has read/write access to the correct files/folders.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I managed to find out that user for xampp apache web server is daemon and running sudo chown -R $USER:daemon /opt/lampp/htdocs/ fixed problem.

Answer (score 1):

Inside httpd.conf User is daemon and Group is daemon.
Without editing httpd.conf file I ran this command.

chown -R $USER:daemon /opt/lampp/htdocs/

It solved the problem.